# Embedding a specific revision of a Gist on GitHub.com via JavaScript

Tags: github

[gist.github.com](http://gist.github.com) has a great [feature](https://github.com/blog/122-embedded-gists) where you can embed the current version of a file in a blog via a `<script/>` tag.

However, I can't seem to embed an older revision, or the current atomic revision in such a way, that further commits won't update what's embedded by the embed tag. Is this possible?

Comment: So you want to post *static* content that is highlighted basically.

Comment: @phwd Well, the idea is that I would have a blog article about a specific revision of the file. In the future I might have a different revision, which I might or might not embed anywhere. Now imagine if this embed functionality was part of regular github repos. Maybe I wanted to embed a particular commit in a blog (or bug tracking system)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add `.js` to the end of the URL like this: `https://gist.github.com/1522901/0f74d53b18060f6292db9dc4d6c1922f72aa2aaf.js`

Comment: no longer works

Comment: Works for me still, to get the very first revision of the above Gist (with an ugly `eval()` that is removed in later revisions) you can include this js: https://gist.github.com/aconrad/1522901/2d94b723ff3ae08c502ac29c1ecf761283a5f296.js

Answer (score 1):

Unless Github makes this possible (perhaps with a feature request/service hook), one easy way would be to simply display the contents of the gist using its complete url along with the commit hash, such as https://gist.github.com/1522901/0f74d53b18060f6292db9dc4d6c1922f72aa2aaf, and then just use some third party code highlighting library for displaying it.